# Show whether or not the functions $f(x,y)=|x|^y$, $g(x,y)=|x|^{|1/y|}$ have limits at $(0,0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, exponentiation

Show whether or not the functions $f(x,y)=|x|^y$, $g(x,y)=|x|^{|1/y|}$ have limits at $(0,0)$.

By the answers only the latter has a limit at $(0,0)$ but I don't know how to prove.

Comment: Have you seen examples of "how to show that a function does not have a limit at a point" with any function at any point?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes but I can't seem to deal with these absolute value functions.

Comment: The key point in the proofs involving non-existence of a limit, is to show that along some path to the point, either the limit does not exist, or showing that the limit along two different paths is a different value. For example, for the first question, if you approach $(0,0)$ via the path $x = 0$ (or via $x$-axis), then $f(x,y)$ is always zero. On the other hand, if we approach via the y-axis,...

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг it must be because im not sure how to deal with $0^x$ and $x^0$ as limits as $x$ approaches $0$ because im confusing it with $x^x$ which has limit $1$.  Can you clarify this.

Comment: $x^0 = 1$ for all $x \neq 0$, and $0^x =0$ for all $x \neq 0$. You don't need to bring in $x^x$ into this argument : along the $x$ axis, the limit is $\lim_{y \to 0} 0^{|y|} = 0$, and along the $y$ axis the limit is $\lim_{x \to 0} |x|^0 = 1$, and since $0 \neq 1$ the limit does not exist

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  Can you provide clues for function $g$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might as well write an answer.

For the first question, we note that if $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ were to exist and equal $L$, then for every pair of subsequences $x_n \to 0,y_n \to 0$ we should have $f(x_n,y_n) \to L$ (as a sequence). However, considering for example $(x_n,y_n) = (0,\frac 1n)$ we have $f(x_n,y_n) = 0^{\frac 1n} = 0 \to 0$ ,and with $(x_n,y_n) = (\frac 1n,0)$ we have $f(x_n,y_n) = \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^0 = 1 \to 1$, and $0 \neq 1$ so no candidate for $L$ can exist.

---

For the second question, we have tho show that the limit of $|x|^{\frac 1{|y|}}$ exists at $(0,0)$. By travelling along the $x$ axis, a guess of the limit value is $0$.

To show that the limit is zero, fix $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose that $|x| < \min\{\frac 12,\epsilon\}$(nothing special about half, can take anything smaller than one) and $|y| < 1$. Then, $|x| < 1$, so if $a>b$ then $|x|^a < |x|^b$. Furthermore, $|y| < 1$ means $\frac 1{|y|} > 1$, which means that $|x|^{\frac 1{|y|}} < |x| < \epsilon$.

We have shown therefore, that $|x| < \min\{\frac 12,\epsilon\}$ and $|y|<1$ implies $|x|^{\frac 1{|y|}}<\epsilon$. Can you do it from here?

Comment: Don't you need to find $\delta$ such that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ gives you that inequality?

Comment: Can you produce it with the info given

Comment: Do you mean to use the fact that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq |x| + |y|$?

Comment: Exactly, use that relation

Comment: Have you managed to complete the argument?

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance. Please keep the procedure in mind, it will be helpful in the future.